# Select rows in Sequelize where belongs-to-many association does not exist?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, join, sequelize.js

I have three models in Sequelize: `Foo`, `Bar`, and `FooBar`:

```
FooBar.associate = models => {
  models.Foo.belongsToMany(Bar, { through: FooBar });
  models.Bar.belongsToMany(Foo, { through: FooBar });
}
```

I want to select all rows in `Foo` where no corresponding row exists in `FooBar` for `fooId` equalling that of the `Foo` model, and for `barId` equalling a specific value.

In SQL it would look something like this:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT
    1
  FROM
    fooBar
  WHERE
    fooBar . fooId = foo . fooId AND
    fooBar . barId = <arbitrary value>
)
```

I understand that I can use a raw query, but obviously I would rather use a Sequelize query for completing this.

Comment: Hey! Did you manage to solve this? I have the same question and would appreciate any hint 